# How can I make my try and except work?

Tags: python, try-catch

I cannot figure why my try and except is not working for decimals. I am trying to get someone to enter a number between 1 - 0 and make a try and except that will catch out if someone enters a number over 1 or below 0 and then it will return the function and make them enter a new number

```
Prison = []

def prison():
    try:
        print("prison rate of children, adults and teenagers, the prison rate must be between 0-1")
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        Prison.append(int(input("enter the prison rate of children : ")))
        Prison.append(int(input("enter the prison rate of adults : " )))
        Prison.append(int(input("enter the prison rate of teenagers : ")))
    except:
        print("it has to be between 0-1, try again")
```

Output:

```
prison rate of children, adults and teenagers, the prison rate must be between 0-1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
enter the prison rate of children : 0.25
it has to be between 0-1, try again
```

Comment: sorry my when i copied and pasted i forgot to put it in code

Comment: If you add 4 spaces to the beginning of every line of code it will format it in a code block and make it easier to identify as code.

Comment: Why are you calling `int()` on a floating-point number?  Use `float()` instead.

Comment: "Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, it can be a plain integer, a long integer, or a floating point number. If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero. If the argument is outside the integer range, the function returns a long object instead."

Comment: in this case, x is not a floating point number; it is a string.  I should have more properly said _why are you calling `int()` on a string that looks like a floating-point number?_

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in your code that actually raises an exception for floats that are not between 0 and 1. One way to manually raise an exception would be this:

```
def _validate_input(value):
    if not (0 < value < 1):
        raise ValueError("Value range must be between 0-1")
    return value

def prison(): 
    try:
        print("prison rate of children, adults and teenagers, the prison rate must be between 0-1") 
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------") 
        Prison.append(_validate_input(int(input("enter the prison rate of children : ")))
        Prison.append(_validate_input(int(input("enter the prison rate of adults : " ))) 
        Prison.append(_validate_input(int(input("enter the prison rate of teenagers : ")))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: `int(input(...))` certainly can raise an exception.

Comment: @JohnGordon, you're of course correct; bad wording on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a custom exception:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass

try:
    my_input = float(input('enter the prison rate of adults: '))
    if not (0 <= my_input <= 1):
        raise MyException('it has to be between 0-1, try again')
except MyException as e:
    print(e)
```

And if `0.25` is a possible value, you should convert the input to `float` instead of `int`.